# Can I use ML kit Face detection to tell if the photo contains a face or not?

Tags: firebase, image-processing, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

This sounds simple enough, But I can't see any attributes I can use from the returned information. I need to go through a list of photos, and for each decide if it contains a face or not.
Using Firebase's ML kit, I see I can get back information about things like the angle of the head, or the probability of the face smiling, or the eyes being open.
But what I need is much simpler. I just need to know if a face exists in the photo or not?

I can check for all the probabilities being 0 maybe and by that figure that there's no face in the photo, but I don't like that approach.
Any ideas? I'll be happy to know if there's a different library you'd might recommend for that.
I am doing this for a school project, so I need a free solution.

- I need this to work for image files. I don't need to use it with a live camera view.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I realized that the return value after a successful detection is a list of all the faces found in the image. A simple check for the size of the list would imply whether there are any faces in it (size is bigger than 0) or not (size is 0).